# How to receive viber REST API callbacks (using java, spring)?

Tags: java, spring, rest, viber

I'm trying to make viber bot (public account) using java/spring. I succeed with setting webhook for the bot (by deploying it to heroku and making post request

`{
   "url":"https://my.host.com"
}`

using Postman) and now I'm trying to receive messages from users. The problem is that I'm a newbie in using spring and don't actually know how to receive any viber events.

Here is my code (just checking if I can receive viber callbacks):

```
@RestController 
@SpringBootApplication 
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping
public String request(@RequestHeader("X-Viber-Content-Signature") String serverSideSignature) {
    System.out.println("Here we go!");
    System.out.println(serverSideSignature);
    return "Hello world!";
}
}
```

However, this doesn't works. If I make request with required `serverSideSignature`(example from documentation) using Postman, such as

`{
   "event":"message",
   "timestamp":1457764197627,
   "message_token":4912661846655238145,
   "sender":{
      "id":"01234567890A=",
      "name":"John McClane",
      "avatar":"http://avatar.example.com",
      "country":"UK",
      "language":"en",
      "api_version":1
   },
   "message":{
      "type":"text",
      "text":"a message to the service",
      "media":"http://example.com",
      "location":{
         "lat":50.76891,
         "lon":6.11499
      },
      "tracking_data":"tracking data"
   }
}`,

I can see an console output. But it does not work if I send message to bot (don't even get any information from logs). I guess the problem is that I do not understand properly how viber sends any information to my webhook, but maybe there is someone who can explain that for me? Thanks a lot.

P.S. [Viber REST API documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#callbacks)

Answer (score 1):

@RequestMapping uses GET method by default and Viber sends a callback to a webhook using POST method. Try to change @RequestMapping to @PostMapping and of course, you should be sure that your webhook is set correctly and your URL has a valid and official SSL certificate from a trusted CA.